# Add dynamic input field into widget form in wordpress admin

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am making a wordpress widget that creates a slide show. I would like it to support a dynamic number of images in the slide, so I need to add an extra input field for each new uploaded image in the admin form of the widget.

My problem is that I cannon figure out how to pass the values of the dynamicly created fields into the widget `update()` function.

I have an array that holds the image paths in the back-end of the widget and my goal is to fill that array with the values of the created input fields.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing how widgets work I believe this is not possible (to have dynamic number of input fields). What you can do since you enter plain text anyway is to add all image paths in one input field with some separator and than split when displaying on front end.

Comment: Thats really smart, never thought of that, while probably not the pretiest of solutions I think it will work. Thanks so much!

Comment: That is current state of things with widgets. More complex and better solution would be to build plugin for slideshows and then use custom post type slideshow to generate slideshows, than use widget just to display them. But it could be overkill depending of your requirements.